How can I set performance column value depends on SDI values?
I want to set performance column value depends on the values in SDI column in Interactive grid
I tried the following :
1- created page button and created dynamic action
2- I created the following java script code when click the button execute the code but its not working and not calculating the value this is the code :
var widget = apex.region('validate').widget();
var grid = widget.interactiveGrid('getViews','grid');
var model = grid.model;
var v_amount = 0; 

model.forEach(function (r) {

if (model.getValue( r , "SDI") >= 0 &&  model.getValue( r , "SDI") <= 1 ) 
{
    
      v_amount += 1
      model.setValue('PERF_ID',v_amount)
      //$s("PERF_ID",v_amount)
}
else if 
(model.getValue( r , "SDI") <= 0 &&  model.getValue( r , "SDI") >= -1 ) 
{
    
      v_amount += 1
      model.setValue('PERF_ID',v_amount)
      //$s("PERF_ID",v_amount)
}

else if 
(model.getValue( r , "SDI") >= 1.01 &&  model.getValue( r , "SDI") <= 1.5 ) 
{
    
      v_amount += 2
      model.setValue('PERF_ID',v_amount)
      //$s("PERF_ID",v_amount)
}

else if 
(model.getValue( r , "SDI") <= -1.01 &&  model.getValue( r , "SDI") >= -1.5 ) 
{
    
      v_amount += 2
      model.setValue('PERF_ID',v_amount)
      //$s("PERF_ID",v_amount)
}
else if 
(model.getValue( r , "SDI") >= 1.6 &&  model.getValue( r , "SDI") <= 2 ) 
{
    
      v_amount += 3
      model.setValue('PERF_ID',v_amount)
      //$s("PERF_ID",v_amount)
}
else if 
(model.getValue( r , "SDI") <= -1.6 &&  model.getValue( r , "SDI") >= -2 ) 
{
    
      v_amount += 3
      model.setValue('PERF_ID',v_amount)
      //$s("PERF_ID",v_amount)
}
else if 
(model.getValue( r , "SDI") > 2 ) 
{
    
      v_amount += 4
      model.setValue('PERF_ID',v_amount)
      //$s("PERF_ID",v_amount)
}

else if 
(model.getValue( r , "SDI") < -2 ) 
{
      v_amount += 4
      model.setValue('PERF_ID',v_amount)
      //$s("PERF_ID",v_amount)
}
})


see the image I need when click performance button calculate and set value in
performance column
PERF_ID and SDI is the columns name
Is the code java script syntax correct ?

You need an extra argument: model.setValue(pRecord, pFieldName, pValue), so also the pRecord as your model shape is 'table'.

Also, while setting the value, you need to use v_amount.toString()
From https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/apex/22.2/aexjs/model.html :
‘The model has very few restrictions on the values of fields. However typically when the model data is backing APEX items or HTML form controls the values will all be strings.’
